# What is the cucumber score?

Tags: discussion, prediction-data

I found [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/prediction-data) and wanted some more information of what my cucumber score was supposed to mean. Another user had it [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39328216#39328216).

What does my cucumber score mean?

[image: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/prediction-data]

[image]

Comment: Your title got me excited for something that sounded funny and interesting >:( Take my grumpy <transcribe-your-image-of-text> (joke?) comment.

Comment: Was there a new answer? What kind?

Comment: Catchy title is not enough, this is way too trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It's a tag

[cucumber](/questions/tagged/cucumber) is a tag on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). ([Proof](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cucumber))

That number that follows it is an "Interesting Tag" score, awarded to all tags that you have viewed questions on. I'm not really sure how they create the score, however.

All this means is that you have viewed at least one question on Code Review tagged [cucumber](/questions/tagged/cucumber).

**EDIT:** It would seem as though cucumber is also a tag on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cucumber) which is a more likely place that you viewed a post tagged with it. Also, see [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299553/what-is-the-cucumber-score/299554?noredirect=1#comment973647_299554) below

Comment: Not necessarily *on* Code Review. Prediction data is global to all sites on the network. All it says is they viewed a question tagged cucumber on some site on the network (maybe they like [cucumbers](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cucumbers)).

Comment: @animuson but that one is most definitely plural. :P

Comment: On Stack Overflow they synonimized cucumber with capybara, which is incorrect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16882090/3648282

Answer (score 2):

It's a tag on one of the sites you visit. For example, it is a tag on Stack Overflow and appears in my personalized data. AFAIU, it is just the score of how likely you are to be interested in questions with that tag on the relevant site.